# Using JQuery UI AutoComplete returns last item in dataset when selecting an item

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been trying to create an autocomplete text field.  I have a textbox that is called `countryName` that the user types in parts of a country name.  The matching country names are displayed and when the user clicks a country name, it's ID is supposed to be placed in a hidden field called `countryId`.

The problem is that when one of the matching country names is selected, the ID of the last matches is placed in `countryId` field, not the ID of the selected  item.

For example:

Enter *Ja* in the `countryName` text field to find all countries starting with *Ja*. The results that are returned are Jamaica (countryId = 108) and Japan (countryId = 110). If I select/click, say, Jamaica - the value that is populated in the `countryId` field (a hidden field) is 110, not 108.

Here's the code I've been working with.  I've used it on other projects but can't find what's different this time to make it misbehave.

```
var c_id = 0;   // countryId
var sp_id = 0;  // stateprovinceId

$('#CountryName').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Ajax/CountrySearch',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { param: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    c_id = item.id;
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(countryId);
        $('#CountryID').val(c_id);
    }
});
```

A second pair of eyes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$.map` in your `success` callback iterates over the response and assigns the global `c_id` variable
2. when it's done, `c_id` equals the `id` of last item mapped
3. you then assign this value on a select event with `$('#CountryID').val(c_id);`

Modify your [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) to return `item.id` as the values:

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.id
    }
}));
```

and change how you [handle the event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) to take advantage of the arguments in the callback and get the value

```
select: function (e, ui) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    $('#CountryID').val(ui.item.value);
}
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/4doz4yuj/